# Python: Calling a variable defined within a function as an input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am attempting to call a value that is defined within a dictionary creation function.
The current issue is the calling of i as an input when it is not defined.

Current code:

```
mass_list=[10.0,15.0,20.0]
def dict_by_masslist(mass_list,input_value):
    dict_created=[]
    for i in mass_list:
        dict_created.append((i,inputvalue))
    dict_created=dict(dict_created)
    return dict_created

pt_dict_pre_names=dict_by_masslist(mass_list,'pt_'+str(int(i))+'_pre')
```

Goal output:

```
pt_dict_pre_names = {10.0: 'pt_10_exp', 15.0: 'pt_15_exp', 20.0: 'pt_20_exp'}
```

This function will be used to not only name things but generate dictionaries of data. When used outside of the function this scripts works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) instead:

```
 mass_list = [10.0, 15.0, 20.0]
 pt_dict_pre_names = {x: 'pt_{}_exp'.format(int(x)) for x in mass_list}
```

What happens here: for every number in `mass_list` we map the number to a string `pt_number_exp` that is [formatted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to include the actual number.